# Insert table Angular module

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am developing an angular app that could use something similar to the word insert table and was curious if there is anything already out there instead of making it from scratch.

[image: word insert table]

Answer (score 0):

The only one I found is [this](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/rich-text-editor/table/) component from Syncfusion but it seems you would have to pay the library license for it. [Here](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/demos/#/material/rich-text-editor/tools.html) you can experiment with it.

Comment: That is exactly the type of thing I am looking for, I'll probably just try and build something myself over paying though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Open-source and MIT License.

[Summernote](https://summernote.org/examples/#example)